# Sublime Text / TextMate scope parameter

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext, color-scheme

Sublime Text (and TextMate) language and color-theme files interacts via **scope** parameter. It is a dotted name, that might be useful in styling (and other cases).

For instance (in XML language file):
`<string>support.constant.js</string>`

How can one style it (besides strict equality)? Can one style this certain item via `support.constant` or `constant.js` or `js`? Does this parameter support hierarchy, and if does in which way (left-to-right or in reverse)? Does styling cascades like in CSS?

I have deep interest in creating flexible color theme that will support not only certain languages, but all, gracefully degrade in case of no special support. For this I need to know how scopes work. It will allow to style common (for many languages) structures, like `function`, `constant`, `variable`, `keyword` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a quite complex color scheme [over at Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme) that you are more than welcome to take a look at for ideas. Basically, scopes work from left to right - to highlight `support.constant.js`, you could use `support` or `support.constant` or `support.constant.js`, but not `constant` or `constant.js` or `js`. Within a JavaScript file, everything is scoped as `source.js`, so if you just wanted to highlight all `support` scopes in a `.js` file, you would use `source.js support`.

For theming, I find the [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways) plugin very helpful, as it shows the full scope in the status bar at all times. Another great resource is [`ColorSchemeEditor`](https://github.com/facelessuser/ColorSchemeEditor), a GUI for editing color schemes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at [Scopes](https://github.com/tushortz/scopes) which includes different scopes for up to 160 languages. You will find it handy

Comment: Thank you, I will look in it from time to time. It looks like it is package of yours. Did you colllect all these scopes programmatically?

Comment: @StreetStrider Yeah I wrote it in python after realizing that manual labour accounts to nothing